# Logging form field value when close modal in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have am trying to console.log a form field when a user closes a modal, but am unsure how to do this.

When I use the code below, the input in the form field is not reflected. Any ideas?

Javascript:

```
.controller('ContactFormCtrl',
 function($modal) {
  var contactForm = this;
  contactForm.agreement = agreement;
  contactForm.contact.signature = '';

return;

function agreement() {

 $modal.open({

    templateUrl: 'views/agreement.html'
  })
    .result.then(
    function () {
      var agreement=contactForm.contact.signature;
      console.log(agreement);
      (contactForm.value1 = true);

    },
    function () {
      contactForm.value1 = false;
    }
  );
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<form name="paymentForm">
  <div class="form-group>
    <label class="control-label" for="signature">Signature</label>
    <input type="text" id="signature" name="signature" ng-model="contactForm.contact.signature" aria-describedby="signatureWarning" placeholder="Signature (e.g., /John Doe/)" class="form-control" ng-minlength=1 ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }" required />
</div>

<button ng-click="$dismiss()" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
<button ng-click="$close()" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="paymentForm.$invalid">I Agree</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have an easier time handling the form data inside the modal controller than you would extracting it. There's not really a good/recommended way to access the scope from outside the `$modal`, especially since there are a few scope layers from the modal itself.

It would be better to have a `save` method or something:

```
$scope.save = function() {
  // POST data somewhere, save to a service, whatever
  $modalInstance.$close(); // or whatever the API is
}

<button ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="paymentForm.$invalid">I Agree</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So is it not possible to pass the text in the modal's input field with the code I'm using now?

Comment: It's possible to "pass" the values if you're handling that *within the controller*. Trying to access those values from an external component will be difficult and isn't the safe way to do it. You'd be diving into child scopes, etc. Where are you trying to pass them? You can fire off an xhr request to talk to the server, use a service to share data, or even fire events.

Comment: I think I might have figured this one out on my own. My goal was to have a modal that requires a user to sign his/her name to agree to the terms of service. When the modal is closed, I want to hold on to that info until the rest of the form is completed. When the form is submitted, I would like the info signature info from the modal to be submitted as well. So "/John Doe/" will be submitted along with the rest of the form.